# How can I ensure a DIV stretches to fit its contents?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML with a table:

```
<div
  class="currentDesignDiv"
  style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <div>
    <img
      alt="Thumbnail"
      src="http://www.propertyware.com/templates/
        <bean:write name="currentTemplate" property="primaryKey"/>
      /thumb.gif"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Your Current Design: </th>
        <td>Template #: 
          <bean:write name="currentTemplate" property="primaryKey"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Last Updated: </th>
        <td>
          <bean:write name="currentTemplate" property="modifiedByAsString"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Total Pages: </th>
        <td>
          <bean:write name="numberOfPages"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Being styled by this CSS:

```
 .currentDesignDiv{
   background-color:#e7e7e7;
   border:1px solid #9c9c9c;
   padding:5px;
   width:100%;
   min-width:860px;
 }
 .currentDesignDiv div{
   float:left;
   width:33%;
 }
 .currentDesignDiv div table{
   font-size:9pt;
   text-align:left;
   margin:17px;
 }
 .currentDesignDiv div:first-child img{
   margin:17px;
   width:80px;
 }
```

It looks OK on my big monitor, but when I change to my small monitor the right-most `div`, which has an image inside of it, floats outside of the parent `div`. Does anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: Please try to put some effort into formatting your code snippets next time. No one likes to have to scroll around because of all the whitespace you've left behind.

Comment: @hdx: Can you please give me the image you're trying to use? since "<bean:write name="currentTemplate" property="primaryKey"/>" is messing arround.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

set

```
overflow: auto;
```

for the outer div. This should make your parent div expand even though its children have a float property. (IE has a few problems with this, but can be fixed by some padding)

Comment: If you have problems with scrollbars, try overflow: hidden instead. You get the same exact behavior, without any possibility of scrollbars.

Comment: @jrista overflow:hidden cuts off the text at the end of the div instead of the div expanding to fit all the text and doesn't show a scrollbar either

Comment: I believe that is only the case if you actually specify a width and height for the containing div. If you do not specify one or both, then the container will expand to contain it's children.

Comment: No, setting a min-width and using overflow: auto on a div does not stretch the div to fit it's contents. Rather, the overflow contents are hidden.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps try giving the outer div this css...

display: inline-block;

Since floated elements do not really have any layout of their own, the outer div just acts like an empty div, not stretching to fit the elements inside of it.

Making the outer div inline-block will essentially make the inner divs take up some actual space in the outer div.

Comment: I might give the outer div a width off 99% as well instead of 100%, since you have some padding on it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually give:

**overflow:hidden;**

I had a problem when i give **overflow:auto;** sometimes the outer div may display scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Float the parent div too.

This will mean that child elements that are floated won't float out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified solution which helped me arrange 3 divs with image backgrounds and absolute text in a 100% width layout.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {position:relative; float:left; width:100%; height:50px; margin:50px 0 50px 0; background:#000;}
.box-fit {max-width:30%; height:100%; display:inline-block;}
#one {position:absolute; width:100px; height:50px; left:0; background:#2aa2fd;}
#two {position:absolute; width:100px; height:50px; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); background:#d4a900;}
#three {position:absolute; width:100px; height:50px; right:0; background:#a7ca48;}
.box-text {position:absolute; width:auto; height:auto; font-size:1em; color:#636363; left:10px; bottom:4px;}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div id='wrapper'>

<div id='one' class='box-fit'>
<div class='box-text'>
Text for div one!
</div>
</div>

<div id='two' class='box-fit'>
<div class='box-text'>
Text for div two!
</div>
</div>

<div id='three' class='box-fit'>
<div class='box-text'>
Text for div three!
</div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8zjgtqcm/